# Column/Scrollview not showing after i made a fixed bottom bar

Tags: flutter, dart

Apparently i tried to make a bottom button for checkout and it seems to be affecting how the body of the app is working. This only happened after i added the bottomnavbar padding etc

heres the link for the snip: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7w48J.jpg

```
class _State extends State<CartOverviewScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Your Cart'),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Center(child: Text('HI!'),)
          ],
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: <Widget>[
            Card(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      'Total',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20,
                      ),

                    ),
                    SizedBox(width: 10,),
                    Chip(label: Text('\$0.00'),)
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            ButtonTheme(
              minWidth: double.infinity,
              child: RaisedButton(
                elevation: 8,
                onPressed: () {},
                color: colorCustom,
                textColor: Colors.white,
                child: Text('Checkout'),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain more about what exactly you want? whats is the problem exactly?

Comment: yes, explain the exact issue you're facing after implementing what you have stated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**you can also try this**

```
 class _State extends State<stat> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Your Cart'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Center(
              child: Text("Hi"),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: <Widget>[
            Card(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      'Total',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20,
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 10,
                    ),
                    Chip(
                      label: Text('\$0.00'),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            ButtonTheme(
              minWidth: double.infinity,
              child: RaisedButton(
                elevation: 8,
                onPressed: () {},
                color: Colors.red,
                textColor: Colors.white,
                child: Text('Checkout'),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It is based on your answer

Answer (score 0):

Ahh i found my own answer actually, the problem was caused by bottomNavigationBar hogging the entire body of the app. i just needed to place the following code from below onto the bottomNavigationBar Column.

```
mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min
```